# how to dynamically set text to an element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an onclick function that that calls a `changeName` function anytime a click event on that element happens.

```
    function changeName() {
    var frag = $('<a href="#0"><span class="Name">change me</span></a>');
    $( ".list" ).prepend(frag);
    var x =[];
    $('.ch-gname').each(function(index, obj)
    {
     x.push($(this).text());
      for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
       $('.Name').text(x[i]);}}});
       $('#action').on('click', changeName);
```

HTML

```
      <div>
       <a href="#0" class="cb-pgcar"</a>
        <span class="ch-gname">Greenhouse</span>
        </div>
      <div>
       <a href="#0" class="cb-pgcar"</a>
        <span class="ch-gname">tree house</span>
        </div>
       <div>
       <a href="#0" class="cb-pgcar"</a>
        <span class="ch-gname">light house</span>
        </div>
         <div class="list">
         </div>
         <div class="list">
         </div>
         <div class="list">
         </div>
```

i want to able to change the text of the class `Name` to the text of class `ch-gname`. My function gives me only the last text text(lighthouse) for the three links.Any help please

Comment: What is `List` ? See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bucr9qsf/). Can you change it to demo your problem; right now it trips with 'List is undefined'

Comment: in the iteration try using $(obj).text() instead of $(this).text()

Comment: Has the same effect...i want to be able to output the different strings in the array  @ABUdhay

Comment: you have to close the each iteration after you push to the array.

Answer (score 0):

The function changeName() has `$('#action').on('click', changeName);` but i do not see any element with id 'action'. Anyhow i've made necessary changes in order to make it work.

1. Added Action id to the elements
2. Changed the `$('.Name').text(x[i]);` to `$('.Name')[i].innerHTML = x[i];`

Look at the below example

```js
function changeName() {
  var frag = $('<a href="#0"><span class="Name">change me</span></a>');
  $(".list").prepend(frag);
  var x = [];
  $('.ch-gname').each(function(index, obj) {
    x.push($(this).text());
  });
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      $('.Name')[i].innerHTML = x[i];
    }
}

$('#action').on('click', changeName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#0" class="cb-pgcar" </a>
    <span id="action" class="ch-gname">Greenhouse</span>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#0" class="cb-pgcar" </a>
    <span id="action" class="ch-gname">tree house</span>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#0" class="cb-pgcar" </a>
    <span id="action" class="ch-gname">light house</span>
</div>
<div class="list">
</div>
<div class="list">
</div>
<div class="list">
</div>
```